# Vue JS - Calculator - read output string as value

Tags: javascript, html, math, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a calculator to test out my Vue JS skills. I have the fundamentals working or at least set-up, however if I enter more than one number (e.g. `34`) I can't get it to read all numbers (e.g. `34`) as a whole value; rather it adds 3 and 4 to the total. The snippet I'm having trouble with is here:

```
press: function(num) {
  if(this.currentNum == 0) 
    {
      this.currentNum = num;
      this.output = num.toString();
    }
  else {
      this.output += num.toString();
      this.currentNum = this.output.parseInt();
    }
},
```

Here's the whole thing on CodePen for better context - https://codepen.io/ajm90UK/pen/BZgZvV

I think this is more of a JS issue rather than anything specific to Vue but even with parseInt() on the string I'm having no luck. Any suggestions on how I can read the display (output) would be greatly appreciated, I've been at this for hours now!

Comment: `this.currentNum = parseInt(this.output);`

Comment: I thought it didn't look right! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is not a method of the [String prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) but rather a built-in function.

Update this line:

```
this.currentNum = this.output.parseInt();
```

to this:

```
this.currentNum = parseInt(this.output);
```

And it is a good idea to specify the radix in the second parameter - perhaps 10 in most all cases, for decimal numbers:

```
this.currentNum = parseInt(this.output, 10);
```

That way, if a value like `022` is entered, it isn't interpreted as the octal value (I.e. Decimal number `18`).