# Attempting to parse an integer from a prompt

Tags: javascript, parsing, integer, parseint

I'm attempting to parse an integer from two prompts (that will take a string) and add the two answers together. So far, the prompts work, but nothing is being written in the document like expected. Can you let me know why my code isn't displaying  properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 2, Example 6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
var firstNumber = prompt("Enter the first number");
var secondNumber = prompt("Enter the second number");

  var theTotal = firstNumber.parseInt() + secondNumber.parseInt();
  document.write(firstNumber + "added to " + secondNumber + " equals"  + theTotal);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strings don't have a `.parseInt()` method; correct use is [`parseInt(firstNumber,10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). If you open your browser's dev tools the console should show an error on that line.  Also you should test whether the result actually is a number, because the user might cancel the prompt or type letters rather than digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue JS - Calculator - read output string as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237978/vue-js-calculator-read-output-string-as-value) but without the vueJS part

Comment: Wouldn't you use `parseInt(firstNumber)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns a string.

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is not a method of the [String prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) but rather a built-in function that accepts the string to parse.

Update this line:

```
var theTotal = firstNumber.parseInt() + secondNumber.parseInt();
```

To:

```
var theTotal = parseInt(firstNumber) + parseInt(secondNumber);
```

Also, to avoid confusion for readers and guarantee predictable behavior, pass the second parameter (i.e. [*radix*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)) - presumably 10 for base-10 numbers.

```
var theTotal = parseInt(firstNumber, 10) + parseInt(secondNumber, 10);
```

```js
var firstNumber = prompt("Enter the first number");
var secondNumber = prompt("Enter the second number");

var theTotal = parseInt(firstNumber, 10) + parseInt(secondNumber, 10);
console.log(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals: "  + theTotal);
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks so much. So it was just syntax. At least I was on the right track.

Comment: Great - if you believe this is the best solution, please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). For more information, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, if you believe it is useful, consider giving it an [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (you will need 15+ reputation first).

Answer (score 0):

When you ran your code it must show **firstNumber.parseInt is not a function** or **secondNumber.parseInt is not a function** because we use `parseInt()` function to convert e.g `strings` to `integer` format so it should be like `parstInt(firstNumber)`. Also check for the `prompt` value before adding the **firstNumber** and **secondNumber** otherwise it will return `NaN`.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 2, Example 6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<script>

var firstNumber = prompt("Enter the first number","");
var secondNumber = prompt("Enter the second number","");
if (firstNumber == "" || secondNumber == "") {
   var firstNumber = prompt("Enter the first number","");
   var secondNumber = prompt("Enter the second number","");
}else{
   var theTotal = parseInt(firstNumber, 10) + parseInt(secondNumber, 10);
document.write(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals "  + theTotal);
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```